# jdbcTemplate - leave field empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, null, jdbctemplate

I have an H2 SQL database generated like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dog
(
  id            BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ...
  breed_id      BIGINT, -- references to breed(id) (see next line
  FOREIGN KEY (breed_id) REFERENCES breed(id)
);
```

Note that `breed_id` is optional.

To store data in this database, I use something like

```
@Override
public Dog save(Dog dog) {
    final String sql =
        "INSERT INTO " +
        TABLE_NAME +
        " (name, [...], breed_id)" +
        "VALUES (?, [...], ?)";

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, dog.getName());
        
        [...]
        
        if (dog.getBreed() != null) {
            stmt.setLong(5, dog.getBreed().getId());
        } else {
            // leave breed_id field empty
        }
        return stmt;
    }, keyHolder);

    breed.setId(((Number)keyHolder.getKeys().get("id")).longValue());

    return breed;
}
```

My question is, how to leave the breed_id field empty in case `dog.getBreed()` returns `null`?

Java wouldn't let me set `stmt.setLong(5, null);` which I understand as `long` doesn't know `null`.

However, what is an elegant way to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@speendo - Kindly use setNull method of PreparedStatement with using java.sql.Types as below:

```java
if (dog.getBreed() != null) {
            stmt.setLong(5, dog.getBreed().getId());
} else {
            // leave breed_id field empty
            stmt.setNull(5, Types.NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that nailed it! Great!